# Iterate over an array of lists without Itertools

Tags: python, for-loop, python-itertools

I have an array of lists `array_of_lists`, of which I need every combination of elements. The number of elements of `array_of_lists` should **not be predefined**. The usual way would be to use `itertools.product(*array_of_lists)`. However, I **don't need to actually save all iterations*** and itertools breaks my memory. I could do nested for-loops but this would require me to specify the number of lists in `array_of_lists`.
What is the workaround here?

Thank you for your answers
Best

Comment: I thought `itertools.product` gives you a iterator, not a full list.

Comment: could you post an example of your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the problem.
Let's suppose your array of lists is name aol.

```
for i in range( len( aol)):
  for j in range( len( aol[i])):
    ... do data handling ...
```

then you can iterate your un-predefined arrays